# Redirect URL embedded signing issue

Tags: embedded, docusignapi

I am using embedded signing...

After signing, the Signer is redirected to Return URL.I am having an issue with Redirect URL - it's been cutoff to the base and ignores the path...

The redirect URL I am submitting is
*https:/www.mysite.com/docusign_return/?customparam=123*

When document signed, I am always getting response with no "docusign_return" like *https:/www.mysite.com/?customparam=123&event=sign_completed*.

I am using a developer account...
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try to change from:

```
https://www.nysite.com/docusign_return/?customparam=123
```

To:

```
https://www.nysite.com/docusign_return?customparam=123
```

I suspect the /? confuses the logic to append parameters which DocuSign has to do.

(also note you have a missing slash after https:)

Comment: Good catch Inbar!

Comment: This is totally my fault. Docusign works as expected. By mistake, I built return URL pointing to the web site when in fact, I needed to return to my API. The API should already have a sufficient route (like "docusign_return") otherwise it would have the same "cut the path" effect. This is exactly what was happening when I erroneously put "Base" URL pointing to the web server instead of API...